# How i generate a JavaScript array with elements selected from subarray of JSON file? (USING RIOT API)

Tags: javascript

This function go to the RIOT API and get a JSON object with stats of my champions used in all 2016. I Want to get my 5 most played champs and save it to a javascript array so i can manipulate the data

```
function mainChampsLookUp(summonerId){
    var zSummonerId = summonerId;
    var zApiKey = "MY KEY";
    if (zSummonerId !== ""){
        $.ajax({
            url:'https://las.api.pvp.net/api/lol/las/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/' + zSummonerId + '/ranked?season=SEASON2016&api_key=' + zApiKey,
            type:'GET',
            dataType:'json',
            data:{},
            success:function(json){

                /* Lógica armar array de campeones mains */
                var mainChamps = [];

                for(i=0;i<5;i++){
                    for(j=0;j<json.champions.length;j++){
                        if(j=0){
                            mainChamps.push(json.champions[j]);
                        }else if((json.champions[j].stats.totalSessionsPlayed) > (mainChamps[i].stats.totalSessionsPlayed)){
                            mainChamps[i] = json.champions[j];
                            json.champions[j].splice(i,1);
                        }else if(json.champions[j].stats.totalSessionsPlayed = mainChamps[i].stats.totalSessionsPlayed){
                            if(json.champions[j].stats.totalSessionsWon > mainChamps[i].stats.totalSessionsWon){
                                mainChamps[i] = json.champions[j];
                                json.champions[j].splice(i,1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of what the JSON looks like? that will give us an idea on how to manipulate your data. Thanks

Comment: First, thanks you so much for answer me!  The structure is the following:
{
id:1321,
datetime: 12415116677,
champions: [
                     name: "Ahri",
                     title: "The Mage",
                     stats: [
                                campo: 123,
                                campo: 244,
                                 ........
                              ]
}
(i dont know how format the text, i did it in the text area but the page show all togheter)

Comment: what i need is get 5 of the champions array elements and save it into a variable Js

Comment: I solved on my own. Tanks you anyway guys